# Developing graphical user front-end application to communicate with microcontroller system

Tags: c++, matlab

I am able to establish communication between my microcontroller system and computer through serial port and TCP/IP, and able to send/ receive data.

I want to develop a graphical front-end application on my PC in which i can view some values/plot some graphs based on the data sent by my microcontroller.

I have some exposure to Visual Studio and MATLAB, and know C/C++ languages.
Which development environment should i use for the front-end development ??
Any tutorials/books/links regarding the same ??

Comment: Use Qt. Popular, cross-platform and easy to use. It's fast becoming a standard in the embedded world too.

Comment: Alternatively use C# .Net, and "charts".
I have a small example wrapper that makes it very easy to create an XY plot

Comment: Hi Henrik, Thank you very much for providing code for reference. I will certainly use it. The flow of the code is a bit tedious to understand, as i am not much exposed to C# language. However, can you suggest some tutorials/books from which i can learn to do the coding myself ??

Comment: Hi Joe, Can you suggest some tutorials and reference material that i can use to get started with Qt ?? From where can i download the Qt for windows ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As suggested by Joe, i decided to go ahead with Qt.

The following links are useful for installing and getting started with Qt on windows.

**Installation:-**
https://zahidhasan.wordpress.com/2014/04/29/how-to-install-qt-4-8-mingw-and-qt-creator-on-windows-8-1/

**Reference:-**
http://www-cs.ccny.cuny.edu/~wolberg/cs221/qt/books/C++-GUI-Programming-with-Qt-4-1st-ed.pdf

Regards,
Abhishek.

Comment: Edit:- After looking further, i found this document from mathworks which describes step-by-step gui development in MATLAB,
http://www.mathworks.in/help/pdf_doc/matlab/buildgui.pdf

Comment: Why is the answer down-voted ??

Comment: Is the post and answer down-voted for fun ??

Comment: Please don't vote-down without presenting a valid reason. It hampers someone's reputation, thereby taking away the rights to vote/comment on other useful posts in the stackoverflow community!!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an appendix to a comment, where I bragged about a small wrapper for charts, for creating XYPlots.

create a winform, rename it to `XYPlot`.
add a chart, and name it `plotChart`

add this as code..

now you can plot easily from your code ..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace Plot
{
    public partial class XYPlot : Form
    {
        #region constructors

        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                this.Text = "XYPlot : " + value;
            }
        }

        //default, used for multiplots
        public XYPlot()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChartStyles();
        }

        private void InitializeChartStyles()
        {
            plotChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = false;

            plotChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            plotChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
            plotChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            plotChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
        }

        //one-offs, used for simple plots of data
        public XYPlot(string name, Series series)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChartStyles();
            this.Add(series);
            this.Show();
        }

        public XYPlot(string name, DataPointCollection XYpoints)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChartStyles();
            this.Add(name, XYpoints);
            this.Show();
        }

        public XYPlot(string name, List<Tuple<double, double>> XYpoints)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChartStyles();
            this.Add(name, XYpoints); 
            this.Show();
        }

        public XYPlot(string name, List<double> X, List<double> Y)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChartStyles();
            this.Add(name, X, Y);
            this.Show();
        }

        public XYPlot(string name, List<double> Y, double xIncrements = 1.0, double xOffset = 0.0)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChartStyles();
            this.Add(name, Y, xIncrements);
            this.Show();
        }

        private void FormPlot_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clear();
        }

        #endregion

        #region getNextDefault
        private List<Color> usedColors = new List<Color>();
        private Color getNextDefaultColor()
        {
            switch(usedColors.Count)
            {
                case 1:
                    return Color.Red;

                case 2:
                    return Color.Green;

                case 3:
                    return Color.Black;

                default:
                    return Color.Blue;
            }
        }

        private Series newDefaultSeries(string Name)
        {
            var series = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series
            {
                Name = Name,
                BorderWidth = 2,
                Color = getNextDefaultColor(),
                IsVisibleInLegend = true,
                IsXValueIndexed = false,
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
            };
            usedColors.Add(series.Color);
            return series;
        }
        #endregion

        #region public methods

        public void Clear()
        {
            plotChart.Series.Clear();
            usedColors.Clear();
        }

        public Series getSeries(string Name)
        {
            return plotChart.Series[Name];
        }

        #region Add
        public void Add(string Name, DataPointCollection XYpoints)
        {
            Series series = newDefaultSeries(Name);
            plotChart.Series.Add(series);

            //shallow copy
            foreach (DataPoint p in XYpoints)
            {
                series.Points.Add(p);
            }

            //invalidates the old surfcace, and thus requests a redraw
            plotChart.Refresh();
        }

        public void Add(string Name, List<Tuple<double, double>> XYpoints)
        {
            Series series = newDefaultSeries(Name);
            plotChart.Series.Add(series);

            //shallow copy
            foreach (Tuple<double, double> XY in XYpoints)
            {
                series.Points.AddXY(XY.Item1, XY.Item2);
            }

            //invalidates the old surfcace, and thus requests a redraw
            plotChart.Refresh();
        }

        public void Add(string Name, List<double> X, List<double> Y)
        {
            Series series = newDefaultSeries(Name);
            plotChart.Series.Add(series);

            if (X.Count != Y.Count)
                throw new Exception("X and Y vectors must be of same length, otherwise I cannot plot them in an XY plot!");

            //shallow copy
            for (int i = 0; i < X.Count; i++)
            {
                series.Points.AddXY(X[i], Y[i]);
            }

            //invalidates the old surfcace, and thus requests a redraw
            plotChart.Refresh();
        }

        public void Add(string Name, List<double> Y, double xIncrements = 1.0, double xOffset = 0.0)
        {
            Series series = newDefaultSeries(Name);
            plotChart.Series.Add(series);

            //shallow copy
            if (Y != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Y.Count; i++)
                {
                    double x = ((double)i) * xIncrements + xOffset;
                    series.Points.AddXY(x, Y[i]);
                }
            }

            //invalidates the old surface, and thus requests a redraw
            plotChart.Refresh();

        }

        public void Add(System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series)
        {
            plotChart.Series.Add(series);
            plotChart.Refresh();
        }
        #endregion

        #region updateSeries
        public void updateSeries(string Name, DataPointCollection XYpoints)
        {
            try
            {
                if (plotChart.Series[Name] == null)
                    Add(Name, XYpoints);
            }
            catch
            {
                Add(Name, XYpoints);
            }

            //shallow copy
            foreach (DataPoint p in XYpoints)
            {
                plotChart.Series[Name].Points.Add(p);
            }

            //invalidates the old surfcace, and thus requests a redraw
            plotChart.Refresh();
        }

        public void updateSeries(string Name, List<Tuple<double, double>> XYpoints)
        {
            try
            {
                if (plotChart.Series[Name] == null)
                    Add(Name, XYpoints);
            }
            catch
            {
                Add(Name, XYpoints);
            }

            //shallow copy
            foreach (Tuple<double, double> XY in XYpoints)
            {
                plotChart.Series[Name].Points.AddXY(XY.Item1, XY.Item2);
            }

            //invalidates the old surfcace, and thus requests a redraw
            plotChart.Refresh();
        }

        public void updateSeries(string Name, List<double> X, List<double> Y)
        {
            try
            {
                if (plotChart.Series[Name] == null)
                    Add(Name, X, Y);
            }
            catch
            {
                Add(Name, X, Y);
            }

            plotChart.Series[Name].Points.Clear();

            if (X.Count != Y.Count)
                throw new Exception("X and Y vectors must be of same length, otherwise I cannot plot them in an XY plot!");

            //shallow copy
            for (int i = 0; i < X.Count; i++)
            {
                plotChart.Series[Name].Points.AddXY(X[i], Y[i]);
            }

            //invalidates the old surface, and thus requests a redraw
            plotChart.Refresh();

        }

        public void updateSeries(string Name, List<double> Y, double xIncrements = 1.0, double xOffset = 0.0)
        {
            try
            {
                if (plotChart.Series[Name] == null)
                    Add(Name, Y, xIncrements, xOffset);
            }
            catch
            {
                Add(Name, Y, xIncrements, xOffset);
            }

            plotChart.Series[Name].Points.Clear();

            //shallow copy
            if (Y != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Y.Count; i++)
                {
                    double x = ((double)i) * xIncrements + xOffset;
                    plotChart.Series[Name].Points.AddXY(x, Y[i]);
                }
            }

            //invalidates the old surface, and thus requests a redraw
            plotChart.Refresh();

        }

        public void updateSeries(System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series)
        {
            try
            {
                if (plotChart.Series[series.Name] == null)
                    Add(series);
            }
            catch
            {
                Add(series);
            }

            plotChart.Series[series.Name] = series;
            plotChart.Refresh();
        }
        #endregion

        #endregion
    }
}
```